# Why is the Filesystem not recognised?

Tags: c, linux, partition

I 'm trying to print the disk status of my current linux partition.Using the following C code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <sys/statfs.h>
  struct statfs S;

  int main(int argc,char *argv[]){

    int i = statfs("/dev/sda3",&S);
    if (i!=0){
            printf("File path error!!\n");
            exit(0);
    }
    if(S.f_type == 0xEF53){
            printf("The file system is ext_fs");
    }
    if (S.f_type == 0x4d44)
            printf("The Partition is MS DOS super magic\n");
    else
            printf("Some other partition\n");
    printf("Optimum transfer Blocks: %ld\n",S.f_bsize);

    return 0;
```

**The problem is that the line `if(S.f_type == 0xEF53)` doesn't work correctly i.e. the condition returns false even when i pass `/dev/sda4` partition (My linux partition ext4).

I searched a lot but was unable to solve the problem.Please guide me here....

**EDIT** The value of `S.f_type` is 16914836

Comment: What output do you get? What value do you get in `S.f_type`?

Comment: 16914836. this is what i get when i print S.f_type.

Comment: You should make that clear in your question.

Answer (score 3):

> The `statfs()` system call returns information about a mounted filesystem. *path* is the pathname of any file within the mounted filesystem.

Instead, you are using it on a *device*, thus you aren't getting information about it, but about the filesystem where `/dev` resides (*edit*: the magic number you reported corresponds to `TMPFS_MAGIC`, so your `/dev` is a `tmpfs` filesystem).

You have to first mount `/dev/sda3` (if it's not already mounted) and call `statfs` over the mountpoint or any file below it to get information about the file system through this syscall.

Comment: Sir, /dev/sda3 is already mounted.  `$ mount /dev/sda3
mount: according to mtab, /dev/sda3 is already mounted on /
mount failed`

Comment: @Midhun: have you read the syscall description? To get information about some filesystem you have to call `statfs` over any file contained in it (i.e. under the mountpoint); instead, you are calling it on the device.

Answer (score 1):

statfs() returns information about the filesystem containing the file pointed to by its path argument. From statfs(2) manual:

The  function  statfs()  returns  information  about  a mounted filesystem.  **path is the pathname of any file within the mounted filesystem.**

When the first argument is a regular file within the filesystem you wish to interrogate your code works as expected.

I also recommend you use a switch statement and use the constants such as EXT4_SUPER_MAGIC instead of hardcoding values such as 0xEF53.